# Jquery .unbind not releasing event

Tags: jquery, html

So I have a class of text inputs in a form. Attached to them is a .live click event as such:

```
$('.post-deal-inputs').live('click', function(e) {
$(this).val('');
$(this).unbind(e);
});
```

This is meant to clear the text on click but only once so that the newly entered user data is not removed. However, for some reason this does not work, it keeps clearing the text on subsequent clicks. I have also tried

```
.one('focus', function(e))......
```

but that doesn't even fire. 
Is there a way, without a switch statement to check the default text etc to make sure the text is only cleard once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers attached with live are not removed with unbind; they're removed with `die`

So try:

```
$('.post-deal-inputs').die();
```

Or, if you've attached other events, then

```
$('.post-deal-inputs').die("click");
```

Note that this will kill all of your events that match this selector.  If you want it to only be removed from a particular item, then I would switch over to the `bind` `unbind` model.  **Just note that this will not work with dynamically added content**

Note that if you're using jQuery 1.7, the preferred way of dealing with events is with [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (and [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/))

---

Because `.live()` is performing event delegation at the `document` level, if you use `.die()`, it will of course no longer work for any elements matching the selector.

If you want to stop the functionality for only one element matching the original selector, just change the class of that element so that it no longer matches.

```
$('.post-deal-inputs').live('click', function(e) {
    $(this).val('');
    $(this).removeClass('post-deal-inputs')
           .addClass('post-deal-inputs-clicked');
});
```

Comment: Hmmm... I have tried both plus `$(this).die(e)` and the text is still clearing.

Comment: Remember that `.live()` is global selector-based event delegation. This means that there's a handler bound to the `document` that is invoked based on selector/event-type. So to remove it, you need to provide the selector instead of a specific element reference via `this` (or whatever). `$('.post-deal-inputs').die('click')` should do it.

Comment: @Right - is there no way to remove it from a particular anchor, only all of them?  I mean, I guess that would make complete sense, given how live works.  So I guess this is one use-case where bind/unbind is preferable to live or on?

Comment: Because it is selector based, to remove that functionality from one specific element, I'd just change the class so that it no longer matches the selector. But my opinion is that `.live()` should never be used. I'd always use `.delegate()` or `.bind()` depending on the situation, or now `.on()`, which is how the API should have worked from the beginning IMO.

Comment: `Change the selector of the item you want to turn off` - you need to add that as an answer so I can upvote it

Comment: Done, though you may have trouble upvoting it.

Comment: Thank for all the input, it was all very helpful! What seemed to work was `.addClass`. This is weird because I could have sworn that I used unbind in the past and it worked, oh well :)

Comment: @RightSaidFred - thanks for *your* help -- enjoy your badge :)

Answer (score 0):

Could'nt you just do something like this, all though removing the bound function would be better:

```
//needs to be run when elements exists in DOM
$('.post-deal-inputs').each(function() {
   $(this).data('value', $(this).val());            //get the text before clicked
});

$('.post-deal-inputs').live('click', function() {
   if {$(this).val() == $(this).data('value')) {    //compare it to current text
       $(this)val('');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.live()` and `.die()` probably aren't what you want in this instance. `live` attaches a single event to the `document` node which fires when an event from an element matching the given selector bubbles up to it (see http://api.jquery.com/live/ for how it really works). Really there's only a single event, so if you did remove it (or only let it fire once) it it would stop all of the form elements working thereafter.

If you have all of the text inputs on the page to begin with you can do

```
$('.post-deal-inputs').click(function() {
    $(this).val('').unbind('click');
});
```

If you really want to use event delegation (because all your form elements aren't on the page when you want to bind the event) then I think you would have to resort to using `.data()` or some other way or marking the elements that have already been emptied, like this:

```
$('.post-deal-inputs').live(function() {
    if (!$(this).data('emptied'))
        $(this).val('').data('emptied', true);
});
```

Instead of using `.data()` you could also use `.hasClass()` and `.addClass()` if you prefer. Really all you need is some way of marking an input as having been emptied and checking that to make sure it's not emptied twice.

Also as Adam Rackis mentioned, if you are able to use jQuery 1.7 you should really be using `.on()` instead of `.live()`